# Aggregate Multiples using Linq from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

The problem I am having is reading the XML file and pulling the multiple PIECE_WGT. Would like to pull the Attribute as well as the element value

Here is where I am having the troubles within the below

```
Pieces = el.Element("PIECE_WGT").Attribute("CNT").Value,
Weight = el.Element("PIECE_WGT").Value
```

Below is all of my code

```
class FILELOGElements
{
    public string FileNo { get; set; }
    public string TotPieces { get; set; }
    public string TotWeight { get; set; }
    public string PiecesUsed { get; set; }
    public double Pieces { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
}

private IEnumerable<FILELOGElements> FileInfo(XElement doc, string FileNo)
{
    IEnumerable <FILELOGElements> Info = 
        from el in doc.Elements("FILE_NO")
        where el.Attribute("ID").Value.ToUpper() == FileNo
        select new FILELOGElements
        {
            FileNo = el.Attribute("ID").Value.ToUpper(),
            TotPieces = el.Element("TOTAL_PIECES").Value.ToUpper(),
            TotWeight = el.Element("TOTAL_WEIGHT").Value.ToUpper(),
            PiecesUsed = el.Element("PIECES_USED").Value.ToUpper(),
            Pieces = el.Element("PIECE_WGT").Attribute("CNT").Value,
            Weight = el.Element("PIECE_WGT").Value
        };

    return Info;
}
```

Below is the how the XML Document is set up:

```
<INFO>
  <FILE_NO ID="2150510370">
    <TOTAL_PIECES>2</TOTAL_PIECES>
    <TOTAL_WEIGHT>500</TOTAL_WEIGHT>
    <PIECES_USED>2</PIECES_USED>
    <PIECE_WGT CNT="1">100</PIECE_WGT>
    <PIECE_WGT CNT="2">125</PIECE_WGT>
  </FILE_NO>
  <FILE_NO ID="2150510371">
    <TOTAL_PIECES>10</TOTAL_PIECES>
    <TOTAL_WEIGHT>1000</TOTAL_WEIGHT>
    <PIECES_USED>3</PIECES_USED>
    <PIECE_WGT CNT="1">100</PIECE_WGT>
    <PIECE_WGT CNT="2">125</PIECE_WGT>
    <PIECE_WGT CNT="3">275</PIECE_WGT>
  </FILE_NO>
</INFO>
```

Comment: You haven't said what's wrong. Presumably the problem is that the values are strings, and your properties are `double` - so I'd suggest casting the `XAttribute` or `XElement` to `double` instead to use the custom conversion, instead of using the `Value` property... but you should really edit the code to start the error. Also note that the code you say you're "having trouble with" doesn't appear in the fuller code - you're calling a `Count()` property in the snippet but not in the method itself... please post a [mcve] to make it easier to help you.

Comment: I changed the Pieces and Weight to String. That helped with it erroring out. What I need is to be able to pull all instances of the PIECE_WGT for the FILE_NO selected

Example: If the user selects FILE_NO 2150510371, I need to be able to return PIECE_WGT CTN = 1, PIECE_WGT = 2, PIECE_WGT = 3

Comment: Do you want to calculate total weight and total count?

Comment: No, Need to display to the user that there are 10 pieces, only 3 have been used, here is the weight of each used piece

Comment: "I changed the Pieces and Weight to String" - that wasn't what I suggested at all, and is a really bad idea. Those aren't *logically* strings, are they? What does a weight of "foo" mean? I've already explained how to convert the values into the types you needed... but now you've basically changed what you're asking. This isn't how Stack Overflow works - you ask *one* question, clearly, per post.

Comment: Jon, my question is still the same as the above.

For a Particular File No I need to pull ALL CTN Attributes as well as the values for the PIECE_WGT Element

Comment: *'Need to display to the user that there are 10 pieces, only 3 have been used'* - how are you intending to convey that with the class you are trying to map the XML to? It doesn't fit.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct way but it was the way I managed to get it to work

I converted the Pieces and Weights to a List so that I can pull all PIECE_WGT attributes and elements for each File Number

```
    private IEnumerable<FILELOGElements> FileInfo(XElement doc, string FileNo)
    {

        IEnumerable <FILELOGElements> Info = from el in doc.Elements("FILE_NO")
                                          where el.Attribute("ID").Value.ToUpper() == FileNo
                                          select new FILELOGElements
                                          {
                                              FileNo = el.Attribute("ID").Value.ToUpper(),
                                              TotPieces = Convert.ToDouble(el.Element("TOTAL_PIECES").Value),
                                              TotWeight = Convert.ToDouble(el.Element("TOTAL_WEIGHT").Value),
                                              PiecesUsed = Convert.ToDouble(el.Element("PIECES_USED").Value),
                                              Pieces = el.Elements("PIECE_WGT").Attributes("CNT").Select(a => Convert.ToDouble(a.Value)).ToList(),
                                              Weight = el.Elements("PIECE_WGT").Select(a => Convert.ToDouble(a.Value)).ToList()
                                          };



        return Info;
    }

}

class FILELOGElements
{
    public string FileNo { get; set; }
    public double TotPieces { get; set; }
    public double TotWeight { get; set; }
    public double PiecesUsed { get; set; }
    public List<double> Pieces { get; set; }
    public List<double> Weight { get; set; }


}
```